# Add fadeIn and fadeOut

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i add add fadeIn and fadeOut jquery animation in every single block of hours "like `hn > 5 && hn < 12`", "`hn > 11 && hn < 15`" etc... after and before every "`document.getElementById("compliments").innerHTML =`"?

I tried to use jQuery and fadeIn fadeOut functions written in javascript but I can't...i don't know why...

```
var q = 0;

var compliments = {
    morning:[
        "Buongiorno!",
        "Ti vedo in forma!",
        "Pronto per affrontare questa giornata?"
    ],
    lunch:[
        "Hai fame? Ehehe credo proprio di si!",
        "Buon pranzo!"
    ],
    afternoon:[
        "Sei stanco? Meglio se fai un riposino!",
        "Esci con gli amici?"
    ],
    evening:[
        "Pronto per uscire?",
        "Buona cena!"
    ],
    night:[
        "Buonanotte!",
        "Fai bei sogni!"
    ]
};

function updateComp(){
    var tn = new Date();
    var hn = tn.getHours(); 
    if (hn > 5 && hn < 12){
        if (q == Object.keys(compliments.morning).length){
            q = 0;
        }
        document.getElementById("compliments").innerHTML = compliments.morning[q];
        q++;
    }
    if (hn > 11 && hn < 15){
        if (q == Object.keys(compliments.lunch).length){
            q = 0;
        }
        document.getElementById("compliments").innerHTML = compliments.lunch[q];
        q++;
    }
    if (hn > 14 && hn < 19){
        if (q == Object.keys(compliments.afternoon).length){
            q = 0;
        }
        document.getElementById("compliments").innerHTML = compliments.afternoon[q];
        q++;
    }
    if (hn > 18 && hn < 23){
        if (q == Object.keys(compliments.evening).length){
            q = 0;
        }
        document.getElementById("compliments").innerHTML = compliments.evening[q];
        q++;
    }
    if (hn > 22 && hn < 6){
        if (q == Object.keys(compliments.night).length){
            q = 0;
        }
        document.getElementById("compliments").innerHTML = compliments.night[q];
        q++;
    }
}

updateComp();

setInterval(updateComp, (5*1000));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have JQuery loaded you should be able to do something like the following:

```
var element = $("#compliments");
element.fadeOut(function(){
    element.innerHTML = compliments.morning[q];
    element.fadeIn();
});
```

You could even wrap this inside its own function to be [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Something like:

```
function runUpdate(text){
    var element = $("#compliments");
    element.fadeOut(function(){
        element.innerHTML = text;
        element.fadeIn();
    });
}
```

Then replace `document.getElementById("compliments").innerHTML = compliments.afternoon[q];` with `runUpdate(compliments.morning[q]);` inside your hour blocks.

## UPDATE

make sure you wait until JQuery is ready before trying to execute any JQuery code:

```
  function updateComp(){
  .... 
  }
 
  $(function(){
    updateComp();
    setInterval(updateComp, (5*1000));
  });
```

Comment: This is the problem, how can I load jquery in the program, I tried so many ways but it didn't  load

Comment: The simplest way would be to add the following inside the `<head></head>` tags of your page: `<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"   integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: You also need to make sure JQuery is loaded before you run your script. You can do this by using DocumentReady: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

You would do the following: `$(function(){ ALL OF YOUR JS CODE GOES HERE });`

Comment: I have updated my answer to better explain the document-ready

Comment: Did this work for you? Could you accept the answer if so =)

Answer (score 0):

You might use a CSS transition to do the heavy lifting for you.  This example uses seconds to show something more interesting.  It take an iteration to *warm up* so give it a sec or two to kick in :-)

```js
var q = 0;

var compliments = {
    morning:[
      "(morning) Buongiorno!",
      "(morning) Ti vedo in forma!",
      "(morning) Pronto per affrontare questa giornata?"
    ],
    lunch:[
      "(lunch) Hai fame? Ehehe credo proprio di si!",
      "(lunch) Buon pranzo!"
    ],
    afternoon:[
      "(afternoon) Sei stanco? Meglio se fai un riposino!",
      "(afternoon) Esci con gli amici?"
    ],
    evening:[
      "(evening) Pronto per uscire?",
      "(evening) Buona cena!"
    ],
    night:[
      "(evening) Buonanotte!",
      "(evening) Fai bei sogni!"
    ]
};

function updateComp(target){
  var tn = new Date();
  var hn = tn.getHours(); 
  var ss = tn.getSeconds();

  var comp = (function(ss, allComps){
    if (0 <= ss && ss <= 15) { return allComps.morning; }
    if (16 <= ss && ss <= 30) { return allComps.lunch; }
    if (31 <= ss && ss <= 45) { return allComps.afternoon; }
    if (46 <= ss && ss <= 60) { return allComps.evening; }
    return [""];
  })(ss, compliments);
  
  // ----------------
  // get the "next" compliment
  // ----------------
  q = q % Object.keys(comp).length;
  var currentComp = comp[q];
  q++;
  // ----------------
  
  // ----------------
  // fade the existing compliment then replace it and fade in.
  // ----------------
  var className = "ghost";
  var duration = 1000;

  target.classList.add(className);
  setTimeout(function(){
    target.innerText = currentComp;
    target.classList.remove(className);
  }, duration);
  // ----------------
}

setInterval(function(){
  var target = document.getElementById("compliments");
  updateComp(target);
}, 3 * 1000);
```

```css
#compliments { transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out; }

.ghost { opacity : 0; }
```

```html
<div id="compliments"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! The program it's perfect but It doesn't write compliments based on hours, it's write random the compliments

Comment: It uses seconds to determine compliments at the moment to make the demo more clear.  You will want to switch the **if** statements to use the hour to determine what set of compliments to use.

Comment: Ah ok, i change the if statements from ss to hn and i use the old parameters  of the moments of the day. Thanks!

Comment: Let me know if you want any additional help